# Retrieve Data from Custom Object in Datatable for a specific Account Id

Tags: apex, class, controller-extension, standardcontroller

I am trying to reference a custom object that has a related list on our account page called "SVMXC__Service_Contract__c" and has a child relationship name to accounts of: R00N70000001hzYIEAY. I need to input on the top data table in my vf page the number of service contracts that the account has. Therefore, the data table needs to reference the account page but I have all of this code in the opportunity standard controller since this is a custom product selection page. The datatable appears on the vf page but no data shows up. I have pasted the code below:

OpportunityExtension

```
public with sharing class opportunityProductEntryExtension2 {

    public Opportunity theOpp {get;set;}
    public String searchString {get;set;}
    public opportunityLineItem[] shoppingCart {get;set;}
    public priceBookEntry[] AvailableProducts {get;set;}
    public Pricebook2 theBook {get;set;}   

    public String toSelect {get; set;}
    public String toUnselect {get; set;}
    public Decimal Total {get;set;}

    public Boolean overLimit {get;set;}
    public Boolean multipleCurrencies {get; set;}

    private Boolean forcePricebookSelection = false;

    private opportunityLineItem[] forDeletion = new opportunityLineItem[]{};


    public opportunityProductEntryExtension2(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {


        // Need to know if org has multiple currencies enabled
        multipleCurrencies = UserInfo.isMultiCurrencyOrganization();

        // Get information about the Opportunity being worked on
        if(multipleCurrencies)
            theOpp = database.query('select Id, Name, Pricebook2Id, Pricebook2.Name, CurrencyIsoCode from Opportunity where Id = \'' + controller.getRecord().Id + '\' limit 1');
        else
            theOpp = [select Id, Name, Pricebook2Id, PriceBook2.Name from Opportunity where Id = :controller.getRecord().Id limit 1];

        // If products were previously selected need to put them in the "selected products" section to start with
        shoppingCart = [select Id, Quantity, Number_of_Years2__c, TotalPrice, UnitPrice, Serial_Number2__c, PriceBookEntryId, PricebookEntry.ProductCode, PriceBookEntry.Name, PriceBookEntry.IsActive, PriceBookEntry.Product2Id, PriceBookEntry.Product2.Name, PriceBookEntry.PriceBook2Id from opportunityLineItem where OpportunityId=:theOpp.Id];

        // Check if Opp has a pricebook associated yet
        if(theOpp.Pricebook2Id == null){
            Pricebook2[] activepbs = [select Id, Name from Pricebook2 where isActive = true limit 2];
            if(activepbs.size() == 2){
                forcePricebookSelection = true;
                theBook = new Pricebook2();
            }
            else{
                theBook = activepbs[0];
            }
        }
        else{
            theBook = theOpp.Pricebook2;
        }

        if(!forcePricebookSelection)
            updateAvailableList();

    }


    // this is the 'action' method on the page
    public PageReference priceBookCheck(){

        // if the user needs to select a pricebook before we proceed we send them to standard pricebook selection screen
        if(forcePricebookSelection){        
            return changePricebook();
        }
        else{

            //if there is only one active pricebook we go with it and save the opp
            if(theOpp.pricebook2Id != theBook.Id){
                try{
                    theOpp.Pricebook2Id = theBook.Id;
                    update(theOpp);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    ApexPages.addMessages(e);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getChosenCurrency(){

        if(multipleCurrencies)
            return (String)theOpp.get('CurrencyIsoCode');
        else
            return '';
    }

    public void updateAvailableList() {

        // We dynamically build a query string and exclude items already in the shopping cart
        String qString = 'select Id, Pricebook2Id, IsActive, Product2.Name, Product2.Family, ProductCode, Product2.IsActive, Product2.Description, UnitPrice from PricebookEntry where Product2.Family = \'Service Contracts\' and Isactive=true and Pricebook2Id = \'' + theBook.Id + '\'';
        if(multipleCurrencies)
            qstring += ' and CurrencyIsoCode = \'' + theOpp.get('currencyIsoCode') + '\'';

        // note that we are looking for the search string entered by the user in the name OR description
        // modify this to search other fields if desired
        if(searchString!=null){
            qString+= ' and (Product2.Name like \'%' + searchString + '%\' or Product2.Description like \'%' + searchString + '%\' or Product2.Family like \'%' + searchString + '%\')';
        }

        Set<Id> selectedEntries = new Set<Id>();
        for(opportunityLineItem d:shoppingCart){
            selectedEntries.add(d.PricebookEntryId);
        }

        if(selectedEntries.size()>0){
            String tempFilter = ' and Id not in (';
            for(Id i : selectedEntries){
                tempFilter+= '\'' + (String)i + '\',';
            }
            String extraFilter = tempFilter.substring(0,tempFilter.length()-1);
            extraFilter+= ')';

            qString+= extraFilter;
        }

        qString+= ' order by Product2.Name';
        qString+= ' limit 101';

        system.debug('qString:' +qString);        
        AvailableProducts = database.query(qString);

        // We only display up to 100 results... if there are more than we let the user know (see vf page)
        if(AvailableProducts.size()==101){
            AvailableProducts.remove(100);
            overLimit = true;
        }
        else{
            overLimit=false;
        }
    }

    public void addToShoppingCart(){

        // This function runs when a user hits "select" button next to a product

        for(PricebookEntry d : AvailableProducts){
            if((String)d.Id==toSelect){
                shoppingCart.add(new opportunityLineItem(OpportunityId=theOpp.Id, PriceBookEntry=d, PriceBookEntryId=d.Id, UnitPrice=d.UnitPrice, Quantity=1));
                break;
            }
        }

    }


    public PageReference removeFromShoppingCart(){

        // This function runs when a user hits "remove" on an item in the "Selected Products" section

        Integer count = 0;

        for(opportunityLineItem d : shoppingCart){
            if((String)d.PriceBookEntryId==toUnselect){

                if(d.Id!=null)
                    forDeletion.add(d);

                shoppingCart.remove(count);
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }

        updateAvailableList();

        return null;
    }

    public PageReference onSave(){

        // If previously selected products are now removed, we need to delete them
        if(forDeletion.size()>0)
            delete(forDeletion);

        // Previously selected products may have new quantities and amounts, and we may have new products listed, so we use upsert here
        try{
            if(shoppingCart.size()>0)
                upsert(shoppingCart);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }  

        // After save return the user to the Opportunity
        return new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'));
    }

     public PageReference onCreateQuote(){

        // If previously selected products are now removed, we need to delete them
        if(forDeletion.size()>0)
            delete(forDeletion);

        // Previously selected products may have new quantities and amounts, and we may have new products listed, so we use upsert here
        try{
            if(shoppingCart.size()>0)
                upsert(shoppingCart);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }  

        PageReference pref =  new PageReference('/0Q0/e?Name=' + theOpp.Name + '&retURL=%2F' + theOpp.Id + '&oppid=' + theOpp.Id);
        return pref;
    }

    public PageReference onCancel(){

        // If user hits cancel we commit no changes and return them to the Opportunity   
        return new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'));
    }

    public PageReference changePricebook(){

        // This simply returns a PageReference to the standard Pricebook selection screen
        // Note that is uses retURL parameter to make sure the user is sent back after they choose

        PageReference ref = new PageReference('/oppitm/choosepricebook.jsp');
        ref.getParameters().put('id',theOpp.Id);
        ref.getParameters().put('retURL','/apex/ServiceRecordLayoutbutton?id=' + theOpp.Id);

        return ref;
    }
}
```

Class 2: ScontractController

```
public with sharing class ScontractController {
apexpages.standardcontroller myAccountController;
Public id Current_Acc_Id;

public ScontractController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
myAccountcontroller = controller;
Current_Acc_Id = controller.getRecord().id;
}

public List<SVMXC__Service_Contract__c> getrelatedscontracts(){
    List <SVMXC__Service_Contract__c> sconList = New List<SVMXC__Service_Contract__c>();
    for(Account acc:[select id,name,(select id, Serial_Number__c, Contract_Status__c, Contract_PN__c from R00N70000001hzYIEAY__r) from account where id=:Current_Acc_Id]){
       for(SVMXC__Service_Contract__c scon:acc.R00N70000001hzYIEAY__r)
           sconList.add(scon); 
    }
    return sconList;
}
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="opportunityProductEntryExtension2,ScontractController" action="{!priceBookCheck}" >

    <apex:sectionHeader Title="Manage {!$ObjectType.Product2.LabelPlural}" subtitle="{!opportunity.Name}"/>
    <apex:messages style="color:red"/>

    <style>
        .search{
            font-size:14pt;
            margin-right: 20px;    
        }
        .fyi{
            color:red;
            font-style:italic;
        }
        .label{
            margin-right:10px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        // This script assists the search bar functionality
        // It will execute a search only after the user has stopped typing for more than 1 second
        // To raise the time between when the user stops typing and the search, edit the following variable:

        var waitTime = 1;


        var countDown = waitTime+1;
        var started = false;

        function resetTimer(){

            countDown=waitTime+1;

            if(started==false){
                started=true;
                runCountDown();
            }
        }

        function runCountDown(){

            countDown--;

            if(countDown<=0){
                fetchResults();
                started=false;
            }
            else{
                window.setTimeout(runCountDown,1000);
            }
        }

    </script>


    <apex:form >

        <apex:outputPanel id="mainBody">

            <apex:outputLabel styleClass="label">PriceBook: </apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:outputText value="{!theBook.Name}"/>&nbsp;
            <apex:commandLink action="{!changePricebook}" value="change" immediate="true"/>
            <br/>
            <!-- not everyone is using multi-currency, so this section may or may not show -->
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!multipleCurrencies}">
                <apex:outputLabel styleClass="label">Currency: </apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:outputText value="{!chosenCurrency}"/>
                <br/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <br/>

            <apex:pageBlock title="Service Contracts" id="sc">
                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!relatedscontracts}" var="scon">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Contract PN">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!scon.Contract_PN__c}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Serial Number">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!scon.Serial_Number__c}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Contract Status">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!scon.Contract_Status__c}" />
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageblockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>

<!-- this is the upper table... a.k.a. the "Shopping Cart"-->

            <!-- notice we use a lot of $ObjectType merge fields... I did that because if you have changed the labels of fields or objects it will reflect your own lingo -->
            <apex:pageBlock title="Selected {!$ObjectType.Product2.LabelPlural}" id="selected">

                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!shoppingCart}" var="s">

                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:commandLink value="Remove" action="{!removeFromShoppingCart}" reRender="selected,searchResults" immediate="true">
                            <!-- this param is how we send an argument to the controller, so it knows which row we clicked 'remove' on -->
                            <apex:param value="{!s.PriceBookEntryId}" assignTo="{!toUnselect}" name="toUnselect"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Product2.LabelPlural}" value="{!s.PriceBookEntry.Product2.Name}"/>

                     <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Product2.Fields.ProductCode.Label}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!s.PriceBookEntry.ProductCode}" />
                    </apex:column>


                     <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.Fields.Quantity.Label}">Number of years
                        <apex:inputField value="{!s.Quantity}" style="width:70px" required="true" onkeyup="refreshTotals();"/>
                    </apex:column>                    

                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.Fields.UnitPrice.Label}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!s.UnitPrice}" style="width:70px" required="true" onkeyup="refreshTotals();"/>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.Fields.Serial_Number__c.Label}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!s.Serial_Number2__c}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:column>


                </apex:pageblockTable>


                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!onSave}" value="Save to Opportunity"/>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!onCreateQuote}" value="Save & Create Quote"/>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!onCancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            </apex:pageBlock>

<!-- this is the lower table: search bar and search results -->

            <apex:pageBlock >

                <apex:outputPanel styleClass="search">
                    Search for {!$ObjectType.Product2.LabelPlural}:
                </apex:outputPanel>

                <apex:actionRegion renderRegionOnly="false" immediate="true">

                    <apex:actionFunction name="fetchResults" action="{!updateAvailableList}" reRender="searchResults" status="searchStatus"/>

                    <!-- here we invoke the scripting to get out fancy 'no button' search bar to work -->
                    <apex:inputText value="{!searchString}" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13){this.blur();}else{resetTimer();}" style="width:300px"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <i>
                        <!-- actionStatus component makes it easy to let the user know when a search is underway -->
                        <apex:actionStatus id="searchStatus" startText="searching..." stopText=" "/>
                    </i>

                </apex:actionRegion>

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <apex:outputPanel id="searchResults">

                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AvailableProducts}" var="a">

                        <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Product2.Fields.Name.Label}" value="{!a.Product2.Name}" />

                        <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Product2.Fields.ProductCode.Label}" value="{!a.ProductCode}" />

                        <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.PricebookEntry.Fields.UnitPrice.Label}" value="{!a.UnitPrice}" />

                        <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Product2.Fields.Family.Label}" value="{!a.Product2.Family}"/>

                        <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Product2.Fields.Description.Label}" value="{!a.Product2.Description}"/>

                        <apex:column >
                            <!-- command button in a column... neato -->
                            <apex:commandButton value="Select" action="{!addToShoppingCart}" reRender="selected,searchResults" immediate="true">
                                <!-- again we use apex:param to be able to tell the controller which row we are working with -->
                                <apex:param value="{!a.Id}" assignTo="{!toSelect}" name="toSelect"/>
                            </apex:commandButton>
                        </apex:column>

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                    <!-- We put up a warning if results exceed 100 rows -->
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="fyi" rendered="{!overLimit}">
                        <br/>
                        Your search returned over 100 results, use a more specific search string if you do not see the desired {!$ObjectType.Product2.Label}.
                        <br/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                </apex:outputPanel>

            </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: if you have the Account id, cant you just query the child records which have the account as it's parent?

Comment: That is what I thought I was doing but no values are popping up in the table

Comment: Are you querying the AccountId field when you are populating the theOpp variable? I dont think you are getting the field in that query..

Comment: Do you know how I can do that and populate it in the vf page?

Comment: Since you are querying the opportunity, so you can add the AccountId field as well. Once you have the AccountId, you can query all the corresponding Opportunities which have this account as the parent.

Comment: how do I query all of the corresponding opportunities that have that account as the parent?

Comment: added an answer below. Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to display all of the service contracts related to the account the opportunity was on. I came up with this and it worked:

scontract = [Select Id, Name, SVMXC__Company__r.Id, Serial_Number__c, Product_Code__c, SVMXC__Start_Date__c, SVMXC__End_Date__c, Contract_Status__c, Contract_PN__c from SVMXC__Service_Contract__c where SVMXC__Company__r.Id = :theOpp.account.id];

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to display all the Opportunities for the Account that is related to the particular Opportunity. You are already querying the Opportunity, so just add the AccountId field to it. Then query the Opportunities that have this as the parent.

```
theOpp = [select Id, Name, Pricebook2Id, PriceBook2.Name, AccountId from Opportunity where Id = :controller.getRecord().Id limit 1];

List<Opportunity> opportunityList = [select id, Name from Opportunity where AccountId=:theOpp.AccountId];
```